# Order email sent to customer but not admin

Tags: admin, email

When an order is placed, the order is sent to the customer and BCC'ed to the webmaster (different domain than the website) but the order is never received by the store admin (same domain as the website).

I checked the database core_email_queue and core_email_queue_recipients tables and see the messages and recipients there. They are not being deleted after the messages are sent.

Can anyone help me figure out why the message is not sent to the admin and why messages are not being deleted from the database? The store version is 1.9.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, sounds like the email service and cron are working fine.

If you are using Google Apps for your email, to be able to receive a BCC copy of the order emails from Magento, you need to add **".test-google-a.com"** in the end of your email.

So, if you go to `System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails`, in the field were you can set an email to receive a copy of the orders should be `email@company.com.test-google-a.com`

You can talk with the Google Apps support for more information about that.

More info [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178332?hl=en) and [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/apps/mail-settings/ZzCzMhjWWVk).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The admin email address is not a Google email address and it is not the BCC email address. The email server log shows no record of the email being received. I'm pretty sure it is not being sent from the website.

Comment: OK, I think I miss understood something. You said that the order is send to the customer and BCC to the webmaster but the store admin don't receive it. Is the webmaster and store admin the same thing? Os is the order sending to the customer AND webmaster but NOT to store admin? Also, could you tell what is the email provider that is not receiving the order?